# "open" command not working after upgrade to High Sierra

Tags: terminal, command-line, high-sierra, preview

After my recent upgrade to High Sierra, the command line command "open" no longer opens much. I have tried it on PDF, PPTX, png. It does work on ascii text files. The 'Preview' app does open if I click on it in the Applications folder.

Does anyone know if there is a issue with running Preview from the command line after "upgrading"?

Comment: What happens when you do `open foo.pdf` ? And `open -a Preview foo.pdf` ? And `open -n -a Preview foo.pdf` ?

Comment: Thanks! I had never tried the flags for open (nor read the man page...). Neither the -a nor the '-a -n' combo, nor the -F flag worked. But after 2 reboots, I did the '-n -a' flag and now it works as usual, even without the flags. Probably some config file or stale link after the upgrade?